# Why does nth-child returns that?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Consider this snippet:

```
<div>
    <div class="user_photo"></div>
    <h5><b>Jane Doe,</b> 01 May 2016</h5>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="user_photo"></div>
    <h5><b>Jane Doe,</b> 01 May 2016</h5>
</div>
```

When searching `jQuery('div.user_photo:nth-child(0)')` I get:

```
[<div class=​"user_photo">​</div>​, <div class=​"user_photo">​</div>​]
```

Why don't I get the first div from this array? How would I obtain the first element of the array without adding a new class?

Comment: ...because you are using nth-child for divs with the `user-photo` class.

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery('div.user_photo')[0]`?

Comment: Hint: `div.user_photo:nth-child[1]` **should** return `[<h5></h5>,<h5></h5>]`. That's what nth-child means

Comment: @slebetman: _“Hint: div.user_photo:nth-child[1] should return [<h5></h5>,<h5></h5>]. That's what nth-child means”_ – no, it’s not. What you are saying doesn’t make sense - the h5 are not even in a parent-child relationship with those div elements.

Comment: @CBroe: Ah crap. Yeah, missed that somehow.

Answer (score 1):

the `nth-child` selector actually means if the selected element is the `nth-child` of its parent.

So in your case, `.user_photo` is the first child of each of its parent `div`. To test this, switch the `.user_photo` div and the `h5` around for one of the elements, and you'll see that it only selects one of the `.user_photo` divs.

To do what you want, I would put a class on that anonymous div, and then do `.anonymous-div:first-child .user_photo`. If you can't put a class on that div, then you may need to traverse to it using another parent element that has a more unique identifier, so something like `#common-parent > div:first-child .user_photo`

Answer (score 0):

The selector `div.user_photo:nth-child(0)` refers to  every div having the class user_photo *and* being the first child of their parent.

To "get" only the first element of this array you could use the [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) function, assuming the snippet you posted is the first appearance of divs having the `user_photo` class.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("user_photo")[0];
// the first div having user_photo as a class
```

Comment: That is I need to find 'user_photo' in the parent unit, right?

Comment: Forget the parent unit. With `document.getElementsByClass('user_photo')` you have a list of every div with that class in the document. Then, pointing to the first one with `document.getElementsByClass('user_photo')[0]` provides you with the first div, in the document, that have the `user_photo` class.

Comment: _“The selector div.user_photo:nth-child(0) refers to the first child of every div having the class user_photo”_ – no, it doesn’t. It selects all `div` elements with the class `user_photo` that are the first child of _their_ parent element.

Answer (score 0):

try doing nth of type.

```
jQuery('div.user_photo:nth-of-type(0)')
```